# IntelliJ 11 indexing time compared to IntelliJ9

Tags: intellij-idea

I can't find much written about this anywhere but a team of us currently work on a very large project that intelliJ seems to spend quite a while indexing, even on powerful machines.

We are trying to justify the spending of the license for intelliJ 11 and if the indexing time was reduced this would help out cause. Is there any notable time difference in indexing or overall stability?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this blog post](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/12/intellij-idea-11-rc2-its-getting-faster-all-the-time/), index speed is indeed improved in IntelliJ IDEA 11. Nothing blocks you from installing the trial version and trying it yourself. If you find that performance is still not acceptable, [provide a CPU snapshot](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-192).

There is also similar post for [IDEA 10 vs IDEA 9](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/12/intellij-idea-10-rc-3-indexing-speed-improvements/) speed.

[image: index speed 11 vs 10]

[image: index speed 10 vs 9]

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I didn't find that on the jet beans site. Interesting little read.

Comment: Also, version 10 Vs 9 http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/12/intellij-idea-10-rc-3-indexing-speed-improvements/